# Importing and rendering promise in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx

**UPDATED**

```
import scraper from 'scraper.js';

class Menu extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: ''
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    scraper.then(data => {this.setState({data});
    });
}

  render() {
    return <ul>{
      this.state.data.length?
        this.state.data.map(function(item, i) {
            return <li key={i}>{item}</li> }) :
        <li>No data</li>
    }</ul>
  }
};
```

I know this isn't right but I can't figure out why? at the very least i'm trying to console.log my data to my browswer's console... eventually what I want to do is dispaly the items in data (data is an array) as a list in my dom, using `<li>` per each item in the array...

Comment: i thought componentDidMount was for promises constructed inside of the react component? @Li357

Comment: Asynchrony is the issue here. What you do is do `scraper.then(...)` in `componentDidMount` and after you receive the data, set state. Then, in render, check if data is in state. If yes, use `Array#map` to map to React components. If not, you could show a loading icon or some kind of UI

Comment: @Li357 do you mean like this? (updated question)

Comment: close. I would actually set data to null or something similar initially, not an empty string. Now you can use `Array#map` to create the `li`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let scraper = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  let results = ["Black Forest Ham", "Chicken & Bacon Ranch Melt", "Cold Cut Combo", "Corned Beef Reuben", "Italian B.M.T.®", "Meatball Marinara", "Oven Roasted Chicken", "Roast Beef", "Rotisserie-Style Chicken", "Spicy Italian", "Steak & Cheese", "Subway Club®", "Sweet Onion Chicken Teriyaki", "Classic Tuna", "Turkey Breast", "Turkey Reuben", "Veggie Delite®"];
  resolve(results);
})

class Menu extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { data: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    scraper.then(data => this.setState({data}));
  }

  render() {
    return <ul>{
      this.state.data.length?
        this.state.data.map(d => <li key={d}>{d}</li>) :
        <li>No data</li>
    }</ul>
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Menu />, document.body)
```

Comment: I guess setState here  is a asynchronous call. So it doesn't guarantee the updated value on render .

Comment: @sumit it doesn't need to have an updated value on the first render—I've provided a default value and check if the data has a length or not

Comment: let say the ajax call is still loading and the render is called before the ajax cycle completed, how  will be data updated after successful response from ajax? . I mean to say that  component inside render are not reactive.Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: this is great but it's saying No Data, aka the data from scraper is not being accessed here...

Comment: @sumit `this.setState` being called when the scraper is done fetching data is what triggers the render to happen again

Comment: @Naji I can't control whatever your scraper is doing. But if it calls `setState` when it's done getting data, then this will work

Comment: @Naji `this.setState` will always result in a re-render if the data changed and you didn't override `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: @james_womack `scraper` is exporting a `new Promise` which is sending `resove(results)` to this react component...

Comment: @Naji is results an array with more than one item in it?

Comment: @james_womack it definitely is, because I was able to `console.log()` it in my routers.js file. I'm trying to start a chat with you but stackoverflow won't let me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161149/discussion-between-james-womack-and-naji).